# Linear algebra way to solve rather than algebraic?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a cleaner way to solve the following for the $\lambda$:

$\det(\lambda A-B)=0$

rather than expanding the determinant and algebraically finding the roots?  I am comparing covariance matrices according to [this article](http://www.uni-stuttgart.de/gi/research/schriftenreihe/quo_vadis/pdf/foerstner.pdf).  I see in the proofs of the article that $\lambda (A, B) = \lambda (A B^{-1})$.  Could the eigenvalues of $A B^{-1}$ then be used in Equation (4) of the above article?

Equation 4:

$d(A,B)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln^2\lambda_i(A,B)}$

Comment: If $B$ is invertible, then the solutions $\lambda$ of your equation are precisely the eigenvalues of $AB^{-1}$, or of $B^{-1}A$, by factoring out a factor of $\text{det} B$ from the determinant. A cleaner way would require knowing something about these matrices. If you have floating point values in $A$ and $B$, you want a numerical method to find generalized eigenvalues. If $A$ and $B$ are given symbolically, then expanding the determinant is the way to go.

Comment: +1 for Ben's comment. These are called "generalized eigenvalues" of the pair $(B,A)$ (or of the pencil $\lambda A-B$). If you want a numerical method, every reasonable platform for doing math-oriented computations should have it already implemented along with the usual eigensolver.

Comment: Incidentally, the article you mention deals with positive-definite matrices, so there is no issue in inverting $B$. A common trick, both for theory and computations, is replacing $AB^{-1}$ with $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$, where $B^{1/2}$ is the pos-def square root of $B$, or with an analogous expression with the Cholesky factor. In this way you preserve symmetry, which is often welcome.