# Generalized characteristic polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, characteristic-polynomial, generalized-eigenvector

Given two square matrices $A,\,B$ of order $n$, of which therefore all the terms are known, let us define the following polynomial:

$$
p(x) := \det(A - x\,B)\,.
$$

I was wondering if in the literature there was an algorithm to iteratively determine the coefficients of this polynomial starting from the terms of the two matrices. I tried to search before asking but couldn't find anything. Any advice is welcome.

---

In the case where $B=I$, according to the *Faddeev–LeVerrier algorithm*, we have:

$$
k = 0: \quad \quad \quad M_0 = \mathbf{0}\,, \quad \quad \quad c_n = (-1)^n\,;
$$

$$
1 \le k \le n: \quad \quad \quad M_k = A\cdot M_{k-1} + c_{n-k+1}\,I\,, \quad \quad \quad c_{n-k} = -\frac{\text{tr}(A\cdot M_k)}{k}\,.
$$

If $B \ne I$ and $\exists\,B^{-1}$, then $A \mapsto A \cdot B^{-1}$ and in the end just multiply everything by $\det(B)$.

But if $\not\exists\,B^{-1}$, i.e. $\det(B)=0$, is there any chance?

Comment: Why not just use an existing general algorithm for finding the determinant of a matrix? The algorithm won't care whether the entries are constants or linear polynomials in $x$.

Comment: If $B$ is invertible $ \det(A - x\,B)=\det((AB^{-1} - x \, I)B)=\det(AB^{-1} - x I) \det(B)$ i.e., we are back to the characteristic polynomial of $C=AB^{-1}$.

Comment: Interesting comments [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/433869/305862)

Comment: See as well the comment I made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1709630/305862) already 6 years ago...